# Rails Edit Action with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to allow admins to edit a user in the current page let's say for example an index page/action that lists all of the users. So when they click edit how can I let them edit the fields on without going to another view? I'm sure this is done with jquery I'm just not familiar with how to accomplish this. Can someone point me in the right direction, tutorial, gem, or other?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with this [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery). It could be worth paying the 9.9$ to get access tot he pro subscription as there are more screencast available that would match your need, e.g. http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery-ajax-revised. The excellent free online [Michael Hartl's tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/) finishes with jQuery/ajax integration if I remember correctly.

Comment: Thanks I forgot about railscasts and I have a subscription :)